# When are uni-grams more suitable than bi-grams (or higher N-grams)?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-mining, n-gram

I am reading about n-grams and I am wondering whether there is a case in practice when *uni-grams* would are preferred to be used over *bi-grams* (or higher *N-grams*). As I understand, the bigger *N*, the bigger complexity to calculate the probabilities and establish the vector space. But apart from that, are there other reasons (e.g. related to type of data)?

Comment: Vector space?! Do you mean the probability vectors, i.e. the multinomial distribution? - Withou 99% certainty, I can say that unigrams should never be used as n-gram language models.

Comment: As Lior mentioned below, I meant a vector space for e.g. TF-IDF.  How would you used probability vectors in this case?

Comment: n-gram language models are meant to define probability vectors over words in a vocabulary, conditioned on a context (i.e. in unigrm case, the context is null hence the probabilities are basically defined as the maximum likelihood estimate: \frac{# of a particular word in the training data}{#of words in the training data} which weak way of computing a probability.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This boils down to [data sparsity](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/ballison/pdf/data_sparsity.pdf): As your *n*-gram length increases, the amount of times you will see any given *n*-gram will decrease: In the most extreme example, if you have a corpus where the maximum document length is *n* tokens and you are looking for an *m*-gram where *m*=*n*+1, you will, of course, have no data points at all because it's simply not possible to have a sequence of that length in your data set. The more sparse your data set, [the worse you can model it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/latest/dg/model-fit-underfitting-vs-overfitting.html). For this reason, despite that a higher-order *n*-gram model, in theory, contains more information about a word's context, it cannot easily generalize to other data sets (known as [overfitting](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/61)) because the number of events (i.e. *n*-grams) it has seen during training becomes progressively less as *n* increases. On the other hand, a lower-order model lacks contextual information and so may [underfit](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/361) your data.

For this reason, if you have a very relatively large amount of [token types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type%E2%80%93token_distinction) (i.e. the vocabulary of your text is very rich) but each of these types has a very low frequency, you may get better results with a lower-order *n*-gram model. Similarly, if your training data set is very small, you may do better with a lower-order *n*-gram model. However, assuming that you have enough data to avoid over-fitting, you [then get better separability of your data with a higher-order model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/155597).

Comment: Just a small additional remark: if tokens are *independent* then 1-grams work as good as n-grams. And e.g. naive bayes is an example that you can often neglect context/correlations. But as you answered, the main issue probably is that you need (exponentially?) more training data the longer your n-grams are.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: Very good remark about independence. However, I think that, at least in NLP, true statistical independence of the phenomena you're trying to model in most tasks is pretty rare-- or am I wrong? Also, the amount of training data required [does indeed increase exponentially](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mooney/cs388/slides/ngrams.ppt).

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do. Naive bayes in spam detection is the prime example where 1-grams preform well. But in other cases, you  want to use at least bigrams.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: Yes, I have heard that about spam classification, but would higher-order *n*-grams not still perform better?-- Otherwise, a sentence such as: "Nearly all the spam mails I get contain words like 'viagra', 'Vi@gr@', ' viaaggggra', 'via.gra' and so on" would ironically be strongly indicative of spam.

Comment: The error of using n-grams can be in *favor* of the desired decision. The estimated probability of NB is usually unusable; but the binary decision spam-nonspam is very good. The position information maybe does not add that much value for spam mails that are largely random words and "viagra"; maybe also because the nonspam texts are so diverse the n-grams there are largely unique.
Simply put: if "viagra" already is 99% indicative of spam, "buy viagra" probably only increases this to 99.9% - same outcome.

Comment: Is it true please that keeping low-frequency N-gram will cause the model to overfit?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, n-grams more than 1 is better as it carries more information about the context in general. However, sometimes unigrams are also calculated besides bigram and trigrams and used as fallback for them. This is usefull also, if you want high recall than precision to search unigrams, for instance, you are searching for all possible uses of verb "make".

Lets use Statistical Machine Translation as an Example:
Intuitively, the best scenario is that your model has seen the full sentence (lets say 6-grams) before and knows its translation as a whole. If this is not the case you try to divide it to smaller n-grams, keeping into consideration that the more information you know about the word surroundings, the better the translation. For example, if you want to translate "Tom Green" to German, if you have seen the bi-gram you will know it is a person name and should remain as it is but if your model never saw it, you would fall back to unigrams and translate "Tom" and "Green" separately. Thus "Green" will be translated as a color to "Grün" and so on.

Also, in search knowing more about the surrounding context makes the results more accurate.